# Javascript написать справа текст

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите,как изменить `console.log` на другой чтобы текст появился с права `input`-а.

Код:

```js
function myFunc(){
    var name = document.getElementById('name');

    if (name.value.length < 4) {
        console.log("Пишите больше 3 символов"); //изменить console.log()
    }else if(!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(name.value)){
        console.log("пишите только Буквы"); //изменить console.log()
    } 
};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunc()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function myFunc() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name')
    , message = '';
  if (name.value.length < 4) {
    message = 'Пишите больше 3-х символов.';
  }
  else if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(name.value)) {
    message = 'Пишите только буквы.';
  }
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = message;
};
```

```css
#message {
  color: #f33;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"><span id="message"></span>
<br/><br/>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunc()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое очень помогли...!!!